# Array behavior confusion

Tags: javascript

In a coding test I have recently encountered a question that asks me to find out what will be printed in console. The question is below. I did not understand how this below code will be understood and executed.

Need help

```
var arr = ["a" , "b" , "c" , "d"][1,2,3];
console.log(arr);
```

What does that arr definition even mean?

Answer (score 13):

Arrays in JS are one dimensional.

So `var arr = ["a" , "b" , "c" , "d"][1,2,3];`

Here `[1,2,3]` represents the indexes.

And comma is the least preceded operator so `[1,2,3]` will return you `3` (i.e. The right most element always).

Therefore

The result will return you the value at index `3` that's `d`

```
Update:
```

Let's see some more points for `comma` operator:

[**From MDN**:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

So, It means:

```
var a = (10, 18);
a; //18
```

Also note that it's essential to mention them inside brackets while assigning to a variable.

If you try something like:

```
var a = 1,2,3;
a; // will return 1
```

So it's important that you wrap them using `()`.

When will you use it `,` operator?

> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple
>   expressions in a location that requires a single expression. The most
>   common usage of this operator is to supply multiple parameters in a
>   for loop.

```
for (var i = 0, j = 9; i <= 9; i++, j--)
```

Now that you've understood about `comma` operator, Let's see few more examples to test our understanding:

```
1.  var a = (1,3)/(2,1);
    a // what will be the o/p

2.  var a = ["Stack", "OverFlow","is","Awesome"][1,3,2][2,0]
    a // What will be the o/p

3.  var a = (true,0,1), b, c;
    if(b,c,a) {
        console.log("Will it execute?");
    }
```

Comment: Correct. OP, at least it didn't look like this: `var wtf = "test"[1,2,3];` which is probably even more confusing ;)

Comment: @DavidTitarenco that's a good one :)

Comment: Awesome man! I learned something new today. I had no idea that the comma token has a special meaning in the language before. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Your example caught me offguard. Here's another example which illustrates what is going on. Essentially a list of comma separated values evaluates to the value of the last.

```
if (false, false, true) {
    console.log("hello")
} 
// --> "hello"
```

Comment: Neat simplification of the core concept