# How is the "d" getting printed for the following code ["a", "b", "c", "d"][1, 2, 3]

Tags: javascript

I was going through one of the interview process this is question poped up

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"][1, 2, 3]
```

when I did `console.log` it is printing `"d"` and I tried

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"][1, 2, 3]
```

even it is printing `"d"`.

Please explain with some documents if you can ?

Comment: if you get the solution please let me know

Comment: The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) strikes again.

Comment: I found the duplicate by searching for [`[javascript] array multiple index comma`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+array+multiple+index+comma), which let me find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249371/array-behavior-confusion/29249412#29249412, which is closed as a duplicate as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first set is interpreted as an array, the second set is evaluated as an indexer to the first.

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"][1, 2, 3] => "d"
["a", "b", "c", "d"][1, 2] => "c"
["a", "b", "c", "d"][1] => "b"
["a", "b", "c", "d"][0] => "a"
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"][3] => "d"
(1, 2, 3) => 3
```

thus:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"][1, 2, 3] =>
["a", "b", "c", "d"][(1, 2, 3)] =>
["a", "b", "c", "d"][3] =>
"d"
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator usage at bracket notation is allowing result of reference to last element of array. For example `var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"][1, 2]; arr // c`